# Display member in Combobox without losing reference to associated data

Tags: vb.net, linq, methods, combobox

I have a TableAdapter for a table like:

```
ID_BRAND    NAME_BRAND    ... (Other columns)
(...)        (...)              (...)
```

I have a ComboBox where I need to add all NAME_BRANDs, but without losing the reference to their ID_BRAND, because there are some NAME_BRANDs identical, but with different ID_BRAND. Thhen when the user selects a name in the ComboBox, the correspondent ID_BRAND must be extracted.

Plus, I need to make a query in a method but problem is I am not sure what kind of data to return.

```
Function returnBrands() As ??

    brands.Fill(db.brands) 'my brandsTableAdapter

    Dim q = From pc In db.brands
        Select pc.NAME_BRAND, pc.ID_BRAND
        Order By NAME_BRAND
    Return q

End Function
```

Visual studio says that q is a kind of

```
 OrderedEnumerableRowCollection(Of <anonymous type: Key NAME_BRAND As String, Key ID_BRAND As String>)
```

But when I try to return this by the method, it returns an error.

I'm also worried that when the ComboBox correctly loads the NAME_BRANDs, how will I extract the corresponding ID_BRAND after the user will selects a NAME_BRAND?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` for a bound source were made for this.  Also. please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Create a type that represents the table you're querying from.  Something like this:

```
Public Class Brand
    Public Property ID_BRAND As String
    Public Property NAME_BRAND As String
End Class
```

In the select portion of your query, specify the Brand type and copy the appropriate values:

```
Dim q = From pc In db.brands
        Select New Brand WITH { .ID_BRAND = pc.ID_BRAND, .NAME_BRAND = pc.NAME_BRAND }
        Order By NAME_BRAND
```

Now your function signature looks something like this:

```
Public Function returnBrands() As IQueryable<Brand>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which value to show using `DisplayMember`. You can also keep a value to associate with what you display using `ValueMember`

.NET has a `KeyValuePair(Of TKey,TValue)` that is handy for keep a related key and value.

You can use a `Dictionary(Of TKey,TValue)` to store your ID_BRAND and NAME_BRAND pairs. You can have duplicate NAME_BRANDs but a Dictionary requires the key to be Unique.

For your needs, you can return a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` from your method and bind it to your ComboBox:

```
Function returnBrands() As Dictionary(Of String, String)

    brands.Fill(db.brands) 'my brandsTableAdapter

    Dim q = From pc In db.brands
        Select pc.NAME_BRAND, pc.ID_BRAND
        Order By NAME_BRAND
    Return q.ToDictionary(Of String, String)(Function(x) x.ID_BRAND, Function(x) x.NAME_BRAND)

End Function
```

Now that you have your dictionary, you can set it as the `DataSource` of your `ComboBox` and set the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` accordingly:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = returnBrands()
ComboBox1.DataSource.DisplayMember = "Key"
ComboBox1.DataSource.ValueMember = "Value"
```

You could also return an object from bind directly to your anonymous type.

```
Function returnBrands() As Object

    brands.Fill(db.brands) 'my brandsTableAdapter

    Dim q = From pc In db.brands
        Select pc.NAME_BRAND, pc.ID_BRAND
        Order By NAME_BRAND
    Return q.ToArray()

End Function

ComboBox1.DataSource = returnBrands()
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "NAME_BRAND"
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID_BRAND"
```

However, the latter approach isn't considered best practice.

Comment: Thank you so much for help!

Comment: Please take a moment to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Tried the code, for now only the one that returns an object from anonymous type, only a small correction: the code that is working for me is:
    ComboBox1.DataSource = returnBrands()
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "NAME_BRAND"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "ID_BRAND"

(so without .DataSource. ... maybe cause I'm using VS 2017, but honestly dunno :(  )
Waiting to test your first one and NoAlias one too.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Oversight on my behalf. If I typed it up in VS I would have caught that but I free handed it.